# Recommended number of items in an RSS feed

Tags: rss

I'm creating an RSS for an existing website and I was just wondering if there is a recommended number of feed items to be shown in an RSS feed?

Can output any number of feeds I want? Like 50 feeds at a time if it is needed?

The purpose of the RSS is to keep the subscribers on the website updated of any new content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the amount of articles in a feed? If so, start with about 25 or 30 feeds.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it really depends on how often you push new content.

If you're only pushing 1-2 new articles per day, then 5-10 results should be fine.

Keep the total results to no more than what your site pushes in a week.

Comment: What if for example the site creates 10 new content per week and I push 10 feeds (the 10 new content) per week as well, and there is a user who haven't updated his RSS client for a week, will he miss the previous week content? Is this correct? Best way to avoid this is to push content at least 2 to 3 weeks worth to cover it?

Comment: I guess it really depends on your average user... My numbers were based more for people who check every day or two.